# Not able to mock data to a method using PowerMockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, powermock, powermockito

I have a code where i am writing Juint test case to check a service API.
Below is the code :

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({PackageVO.class,PackageServiceImpl.class})
    public class TestPackageService extends BaseTestClass {
    packageVO = PowerMockito.spy(packageVO);
    Package Package = EasyMock.createMock(Package.class);
    Package = PowerMockito.spy(Package);
    String OperatorId = "tivo:op.56";
    Package.setOperatorId(OperatorId);
    Package.setPackageType("Mock Package Type");
    PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(Package).setOperatorId(OperatorId);
    packageVO.setPackage(Package);
    packageVO = packageServiceImpl.loadPackage(packageVO);
    Assert.assertNotNull("packageServiceImpl loadPackage", packageVO);
    }
```

My PackageServiceImpl class contains loadPackage Method :

```
@Override
 public PackageVO loadPackage(PackageVO packageVO){
 PartnerVO partnerVO = new PartnerVO();
  if (!packageVO.isParentOrg()) {
    packageVO.getPackage().setOperatorId(SecurityHelper.getOrganization().getOperatorId());
   }
  partnerVO = partnerService.loadPartner(partnerVO);
 }
```

i am trying to mock operatorId to setter method :

```
packageVO.getPackage().setOperatorId(SecurityHelper.getOrganization().getOperatorId());
```

but not able to get this done. Please let me know what am i missing here to mock operatorId to setter method.